# I have .crash report the dSYM file, can't symbolicate the crash log

Tags: ios, swift, symbolicatecrash, dsym, symbolicate

I am sending a crash log gathered from PLCrashReporter to my server, also for each time I make a build a run script works and it uploads the dSYM file to my server, then in the server I am trying to symbolicate the crash log using

```
atos -arch arm64 -o debug.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FakeNewsDetector -l 0x1047d0000 0x00000001047da6d0.
```

the atos command returns wrong line for the crash.
My guess is I use dSYM which is generated by the last build, but I never tried to use dSYM from archived build(I don't have developer membership, can't ship apps to test.).

Addresses took from Thread 0

[image: Addresses took from Thread 0]

[image: Binary Image]

Tried using

```
atos -arch arm64 -o debug.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FakeNewsDetector -l 0x1047d0000 0x00000001047da6d0
```

it returns wrong code lines

Answer (score 0):

You cannot symbolicate using any archive. You **must** use the dSYM from the particular archive that was uploaded.

Here’s the [detailed documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report) describing the desymbolication process.